# Firebase Realtime Database Android ChildEventListener Functionality

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In an effort to reduce data transfer (since it's costing us a lot of money), we're in the process of updating our Firebase Realtime Database value listener to use child listeners. Since most of the fields don't change, and the ones that change most frequently we only care about in certain app states, using only child added and child removed listeners seems to fit the bill.

Adding listeners for just child_added and child_removed appears to work perfectly on web. And iOS seems to be set up that way as well, though I admittedly haven't tested there yet. Android, however, appears to require that we add one massive listener that will listen for child moved and child changed too.

Listening for these, to my understanding, mostly defeats the purpose of using the child listeners over the value listener. Since any time any of the child's data changes (most of which we don't care about most of the time), it will send the entire child's snapshot again. We're trying to avoid data transfer by only listening for added/removed and circumstantially specific child properties, but this requires we basically listen to all of it at all times? Is there another way to implement this, to get what I'm hoping for?

To summarize our object, we have:

```
parent
--child A
----child A property 1
----child A property 2
--child B
----child B property 1
----child B property 2
```

etc. And we want to know when a child is added or removed, but most of the time we don't care about keeping the child's properties updated and would prefer to avoid re-transferring that data. How is that accomplished on Android (using Java, specifically)? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference between the data transferred for a `ValueEventListener` vs a `ChildEventListener` when they are used on the same query/path in the database.

If you only want to know when a child is added/remove, but not about their contents, consider adding an additional top-level branch to your tree, where you keep just the key of the child node and then `true` as its value.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't control the data, I just need to handle it. I can try proposing that as an addition to the system, but the person who would know best how to implement it is no longer with the company, so it won't be fun...

Since web and iOS support individual listeners for the different child events, it seems like it would make sense for Android to support that too. Perhaps an enhancement for the next release? This is costing us quite a bit of money, and I feel like others must be in the same boat.

Comment: While the API is different indeed for iOS and Android, it makes no difference for the amount of data that is transferred. All platforms will transfer the same (deep) data, as that is how the wire protocol is implemented. If you want to check, have a look at the wire traffic for the web client by checking the Web Socket frames in the Network panel of your browser.

Comment: Well that's disappointing... I guess I'll need to start harassing the other team. Thanks so much for your clarification and suggestion!